# WLS CAT Utility deployment exception

Tags: performance, wlst

I am trying to use Weblogic Server CAT utility. host:/wls-cat/
as well as admin console-> deployment-> application->testing-> CAT did not gave the index.jsp page.

```
GET /wls-cat/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic d2VibG9naWM6d2VibG9naWM2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:17101/wls-cat/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=ScnLSmcTnghxv6V1NwqBkdDwT0hzbKM2x2zvvyfqMyyhCBhQndLW!619245397;  ADMINCONSOLESESSION=2rS3Sm1J6WQ50Y82JWbGYpWcptQpkgS4Myxdm52FVtnvNz3rFTRN!389647872

]] Root cause of ServletException.
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /index.jsp
index.jsp:47:8: The tag handler class was not found     "jsp_servlet._tags.__analyzeconflicts_tag".
<mytags:analyzeConflicts appname="${param.app}" modulename="${param.module}"    version="${param.version}"/>
   ^---------------------^
index.jsp:47:8: The tag handler class was not found    "jsp_servlet._tags.__analyzeconflicts_tag".
  <mytags:analyzeConflicts appname="${param.app}" modulename="${param.module}" version="${param.version}"/>
   ^---------------------^
index.jsp:57:8: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__loadedclasses_tag".
  <mytags:loadedClasses classloader="${param.classloader}"/>
   ^------------------^
index.jsp:57:8: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__loadedclasses_tag".
  <mytags:loadedClasses classloader="${param.classloader}"/>
   ^------------------^
analyzeConflicts.tag:202:19: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__analyzeresource_tag".
             <mytags:analyzeResource resource="<%=resourceName%>" classloader="    <%=classLoader %>"/>
              ^--------------------^
loadedClasses.tag:117:19: The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet._tags.__analyzeresource_tag".
             <mytags:analyzeResource resource="<%=resourceName%>"    classloader="${param.classloader}"/>
              ^--------------------^
analyzeResource.tag:14:17: The import sun.tools.javap cannot be resolved
```

<%@ tag import="sun.tools.javap.JavapEnvironment" %>
                ^------------------------------^
    analyzeResource.tag:15:17: The import sun.tools.javap cannot be resolved
<%@ tag import="sun.tools.javap.JavapPrinter" %>
                ^--------------------------^
    analyzeResource.tag:46:5: JavapEnvironment cannot be resolved to a type
    JavapEnvironment env = new JavapEnvironment();
    ^-------------^
    analyzeResource.tag:46:32: JavapEnvironment cannot be resolved to a type
    JavapEnvironment env = new JavapEnvironment();
                               ^-------------^
    analyzeResource.tag:48:5: JavapPrinter cannot be resolved to a type
    JavapPrinter printer = new JavapPrinter(loadLocation.openStream(), pw, env);
    ^---------^
    analyzeResource.tag:48:32: JavapPrinter cannot be resolved to a type
    JavapPrinter printer = new JavapPrinter(loadLocation.openStream(), pw, env);
                               ^---------^

```
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:226)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:162)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:256)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1017876 tells that jslt.jar and standard.jar need to be in WEB-INF/lib. Followed this but still not able to bring the wls-cat app up.

The error is same. Please provide your input on this.

Regards,
Xhings

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

weblogic-host:port/wls-cat/

and enter your Console login credentials

where:

- weblogic-host is managed node host name or IP addresss,
- port is managed node port
- console login is typically: weblogic / password

wls-cat must be targeted to weblogic-host:port managed node.

Answer (score 0):

wls-cat on weblogic 10.3.5 will not deploy if the JVM is 1.7, the deploy works fine on either weblogic 10.3.6 or later or you need to change the jvm back to 1.6 (sun jvms) if you want to remain on weblogic 10.3.5